# Rspec Ruby on Rails controller question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm currently using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3 and I'm in the middle of rspec testing.  Basically, I have a function that is called by a before filter in the application controller such that it obviously gets run every time a controller action is made anywhere on my site.  For testing purposes, I'm writing tests for a different controller but my actions do not set off my before filter function call.  Is there any way to specifically call functions from a specific controller within rspec tests?    I can't post the code online, so no use asking for it :P.
Thanks

Comment: It's fine that you can't post your code. Just make up a quick test case of different code which demonstrates the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside an **it** or **before(:each)** block in a controller spec:

```
controller.send( :your_method_name )
```

And your function is going to be called.

Comment: So if I'm writing tests in "reports_controller_spec.rb" and I want to call a function that exists in my "application_controller.rb", I would put "application_controller.send(:method_name)" in the test?

Comment: **controller.send(:method_name)**, your controller is available at a method called **controller**.